# How to check if a folder exists in a parent folder using App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to check if a folder exists in a parent folder and if it doesn't it should create a folder based on the given path. e.g original path Parent/Folder1 now I want to add a new folder to the original path like so Parent/Folder1/Folder2. my current problem is that when I give it the new path Parent/Folder1/Folder2 it recreates the whole path with the new folder in it resulting in duplicate folders. Here's the script so far.

```
function getOrCreateSubFolder(baseFolder,folderArray) {
    if (folderArray.length == 0) {
        return baseFolder;
    }
    var nextFolderName = folderArray.shift();
    var nextFolder = null;
    var folders = baseFolder.getFolders();
    for (var i=0; i<folders.length; i++) {
        var folder = folders[i];
        if (folders[i].getName() == nextFolderName) {
            nextFolder = folders[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (nextFolder == null) {
    // Folder does not exist - create it.
        nextFolder = baseFolder.createFolder(nextFolderName);
    }
    return getOrCreateSubFolder(nextFolder,folderArray);
}

/**
 * Returns the GDrive folder with the given path.
 */
function getFolderByPath(path) {
    var parts = path.split("/");

  if (parts[0] == '') parts.shift(); // Did path start at root, '/'?

  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var result = folder.getFoldersByName(parts[i]);
    if (result.hasNext()) {
        folder = result.next();
    } else {
        throw new Error( "folder not found." );
    }
  }
  return folder;
}

/**
 * Returns the GDrive folder with the given name or creates it if not existing.
 */
function getOrCreateFolder(folderName) {
    var folder;
    try {
        folder = getFolderByPath(folderName);
    } catch(e) {
        var folderArray = folderName.split("/");
        folder = getOrCreateSubFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder(), folderArray);
    }
    return folder;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try with this:

```
function getOrCreateSubFolder(childFolderName, parentFolderName) {
  var parentFolder, parentFolders;
  var childFolder, childFolders;
  // Gets FolderIterator for parentFolder
  parentFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(parentFolderName);
  /* Checks if FolderIterator has Folders with given name
  Assuming there's only a parentFolder with given name... */ 
  while (parentFolders.hasNext()) {
    parentFolder = parentFolders.next();
  }
  // If parentFolder is not defined it sets it to root folder
  if (!parentFolder) { parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder(); }
  // Gets FolderIterator for childFolder
  childFolders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(childFolderName);
  /* Checks if FolderIterator has Folders with given name
  Assuming there's only a childFolder with given name... */ 
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    childFolder = childFolders.next();
  }
  // If childFolder is not defined it creates it inside the parentFolder
  if (!childFolder) { parentFolder.createFolder(childFolderName); }
  return childFolder;
}

function test() {
  // Call it looking up in Drive root folder
  var a = getOrCreateSubFolder('CHILD');
  // Call it looking up in given parent folder
  var b = getOrCreateSubFolder('CHILD', 'PARENT');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The above code works but I will make modifications to it.

Comment: Glad that I could help! Mind that folders in Drive may have more parent folders.

Answer (score 0):

#### folderExists

```
function folderExists(foldername,parentFolder) {
  let folders;
  if(parentFolder) {
    folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(foldername);//only looks at immediate sub folder
  } else {
    folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);//looks on entire drive
  }
  let fA = [];
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = folders.next();
    fA.push(folder.getId())
  }
  return fA.length > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

This method is slow but it will check all of the subfolders below any parentfolder.

```
function folderExists(foldername, parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("found", "false")
  getFn(foldername, parentFolder);
  let found = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("found");
  return found == "true" ? true : false;
}
```

This function actually walks through each of the subfolders one at a time looking for more subfolders. This function and the one above working together.

```
function getFn(foldername, folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder) {
  let n = folder.getName()
  if (folder.getName() == foldername) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("found", "true")
  } else {
    let subfolders = folder.getFolders()
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
      let subfolder = subfolders.next();
      getFn(foldername, subfolder);
    }
  }
}
```